# PAC Fetch failed with error [NSURLErrorDomain:-1003]

Tags: ios, proxy, uicollectionview

I see this error in my logs and I don't know what it means:

```
PAC Fetch failed with error [NSURLErrorDomain:-1003]
2017-06-08 17:07:56.157874+0200 xxxxxx[27059:7093559] [] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003
```

At the same time I have a problem with a collectionView in my app. Don't know if it's related to the error or not:

Sometimes, and only if the app is used in one remote office of our Company, both with the simulator and a real device, a collectionView that simply receives an images array and show them on the screen, just stops working.

It's not like it didn't just load the images, it seems like the entire collectionView doesn't show up.

I'm testing the same app with simulators and devices in another office (another city) and it NEVER happened to me. Other that that "PAC" error, I only see some auto layout constraint problems, but I see the same errors in my logs and it still works perfectly.

The persons that are testing the app on the remote location say that they have to remove and reinstall the app to make it work again.

Any clue?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 29):

Had a similar problem fixed it by this method. Hope this helps.
The simulator uses your computers network connection, so I recommend checking the System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies > Automatic Proxy Configuration : You must disable Auto Proxy Discovery.

Comment: What's wrong in device?? If this kind of error is coming?

Is there issue of cyberroam restrictions/firewall?

Comment: This answer did the trick. Could anyone explain a bit the reason why?

Comment: This is - unfortunately - not an option in my corporate network. It requires the use of the (auto configured) Proxy.