# Xcode 8 : PAC Fetch failed with error [NSURLErrorDomain:-1003] log on Console window

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, console

I’m getting some strange log on console window while working on project. These are mentioned below :

- `nw_parameters_set_source_application Failed to convert from PID (0) to UUID. This could lead to wrong data usage accounting.`
- `PAC Fetch failed with error [NSURLErrorDomain:-1003]`
- `nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error`

[image: Screenshot 1]

I”ve checked below links but didn’t found any useful.

1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439705/pac-fetch-failed-with-error-nsurlerrordomain-1003)
2. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258702/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1003-a-server-with-the-specified-hostname-c)

**Note :** *I’m using Xcode 8.3.2 with iPhone 6 Plus device (iOS 10.3) and Swift 3 language in Project. It seems that there is no issue with this.*

These logs appears all of sudden although there is no change in my code.
`Most important thing is that my project is working as usual.` So why I’m getting this issue?

Apart from this **will there be an issue when app is uploaded on AppStore?**

Comment: are you using any pods in your project?

Comment: @seggy : yes, whats connection with pods?

Comment: i think it may be.....

Comment: which internet you used ? is there any proxy internet like Cyberoam?

Answer (score 1):

It's system logs that does not make sense in 99% cases. You should disable this logs in scheme settings

Click on scheme icon -> Edit Scheme -> Arguments -> Environment Variables

And add that variable:

[image]

Comment: What about the 1% case??

Comment: it's also disabled my NSLog